# Android custom view scroll performance

Tags: android, scroll

I custom a ViewGroup which is like GridView but support some more advanced features. There is a problem that I set some child view which are FramLayouts who contains an ImageView and a CheckBox. The CheckBox is invisible by default. When I perform a fling on it, it is not very smooth some times. However, when I toggle checked and all CheckBoxs are visible, fling on it is very smooth. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer. When you use `Scroller.fing`, you should use `invalidate()` in `computeScroll()` and when using `Scroller.startScroll`, you should use `postInvalidate()` instead. This is very strange but it works.